# Amazon Product API: ItemLookup with Multiple ASINs

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why I get a particular error. [NOTE: I've masked my AccessKey and Signature parameters]

The url below returns **valid** xml for ONE product.

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[myAccessKey]&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B002UD52WQ&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2010-07-27T23:17:57.000Z&Signature=[mySignature]
```

However, when I use the url below to look up multiple ASINs by comma-separating the ASIN IDs, I get an error

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[myAccessKey]&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B002UD52WQ,B002C0CZEU&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Medium&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2010-07-27T23:17:57.000Z&Signature=[mySignature]
```

ERROR Message:

> The request signature we calculated
> does not match the signature you
> provided. Check your AWS Secret Access
> Key and signing method. Consult the
> service documentation for details

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?ItemLookup.html): "*To look up more than one item at a time, separate the item identifiers by commas.*"

Comment: Sometimes the documentation is wrong, and since they give no examples of multiple ASIN queries, you're kinda out of luck. Contact Amazon.

Answer (score 9):

Silly, but you have to URL encode the commas. Hope this helps someone out there.